# How to secure env file from web page that is deployed by github workflow?

Tags: flutter, github, workflow

I deploy `flutter web` page with github `workflow`.

`.github/workflows/workflow.yml`

```
name: gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
        with:
          baseHref: /onldocc_admin/
```

This process deploy web page based on files uploaded on github as far as I know.

The problem is that `.env` is ignored from github.

So when web is deployed, error that  env file doens't exist comes.

The only solution that I found is to remove `.env` from `.gitignore` file.

But This means I upload all security code is opened on github.

Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score -1):

**1. Store your github secrets:** Go to your GitHub repository, then navigate to Settings > Secrets > New repository secret.

Add your environment variables there. Let's say you have an environment variable called **MY_SECRET**.

**2. Access your secrets:**

```yaml
name: gh-pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      - uses: bluefireteam/flutter-gh-pages@v7
        with:
          baseHref: /onldocc_admin/
        env:
          MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then Can I use secret code as before ? `await dotenv.load(fileName: "env");  ->  dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"]`

Comment: don't load from fileName

Comment: Then how to use secret code in my code? For example, below code: 

`await Supabase.initialize(
      url: dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"]!,
      anonKey: dotenv.env["SUPABASE_ANONKEY"]!,
    );`

Comment: await dotenv.load();
  final supabaseUrl = dotenv.env['SUPABASE_URL'];
  final supabaseAnonKey = dotenv.env['SUPABASE_ANONKEY'];

  if (supabaseUrl == null || supabaseAnonKey == null) {
    throw Exception("Supabase URL or Anon Key is not provided");
  }

Comment: I get error message: Flutter Web engine failed to fetch "assets/.env" -> I post more question regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053113/error-while-trying-to-load-an-asset-flutter-web-engine-failed-to-fetch-assets