# Error while trying to load an asset: Flutter Web engine failed to fetch "assets/.env"

Tags: flutter, github, workflow

I have `.env` file and deployed `flutter web` with `github workflow`.

Since .env file is ignored by `.gitignore` I tried to add .env file manually by adding values to github `Secret Actions` and then writing script workflow.yml as below.

**workflow.yml**

```yaml
      - name: Create.env
        shell: bash
        env:
          SUPABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}
          SUPABASE_ANONKEY: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }}
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo SUPABASE_URL=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }} >> .env
          echo SUPABASE_ANONKEY=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANONKEY }} >> .env
          cat .env
```

And I comment `.env` from `pubspec.yml`.

```yaml
  assets:
    # - .env
    - assets/images/
    - assets/app_intro/
    - assets/app_screen/
```

If I don't treat this as comment, it throws error when deploying web with github as below error message.

> Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                           No
> file or variants found for asset: .env. Error detected in
> pubspec.yaml:

And I use these secret values in my code as below.

```dart
   await dotenv.load();

    final supabaseUrl = dotenv.env["SUPABASE_URL"];
    final supabaseAnonKey = dotenv.env["SUPABASE_ANONKEY"];

    if (supabaseUrl == null || supabaseAnonKey == null) {
      throw Exception("Supabase URL or Anon Key is not provided");
    }

    await Supabase.initialize(
      url: supabaseUrl,
      anonKey: supabaseAnonKey,
    );
```

`build` is done successfully.

But when I open web, it throws error.

> main.dart.js:9456 Error while trying to load an asset: Flutter Web
> engine failed to fetch "assets/.env". HTTP request succeeded, but the
> server responded with HTTP status 404.

I don't understand why it tried to fetch from `assets/.env`, not `.env` and how to resolve this issue.